# How to compile directories of python code

Tags: python

I am new to python. I have a directory of *.py files and subdirectory of *.py files, how can I compile them to catch any syntax error?

Thank you.

Comment: `python -m compileall ...`

Comment: `python *.py <subdirectory>/*.py`?

Comment: i get this when i do `python -m compileall ...` Listing '...'...
Can't list '...'

Comment: I think what @AnthonySottile meant was for you to replace the dots with the path to your directory/folder.

Comment: Thank you. @justin

Comment: I think you want to lint the files for syntax errors, not compile them.

Answer (score 0):

To compile all .py file in suppose 'Lib/' directory :

```py
import compileall
compileall.compile_dir('Lib/', force=True)
```

For more information on the python files compilation, please follow this link. https://docs.python.org/3/library/compileall.html